# Why does hash changes even when the data remains the same?

Tags: terminal, hash

Checked the hash of the original file(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywUy4.png)

Changed the data in amount from 1000 to 9000(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDVz.png)

Hash of the changed data(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC9cp.png)

Changed the file to original and it has the same hash(https://i.stack.imgur.com/btIy3.png)

Overwrite the same file using jp and sponge but the hash is different(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHFw4.png)

I was expecting that the hash would be same irrespective of the method of changing the data

Comment: If the hash is different, something in thos files must be different, as the hash depends only on the content of the files. From your screenshot, we can not say for sure whether the files are identical or not. Compare the two files which yield different hash using `cmp`.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: The hash is telling you not to trust your lying eyes. Listen to the hash, it is wise.